# Changing linked table location programmatically

Tags: vba, ms-access, linked-tables

I have an Access database with a linked table in a second database, located in the same directory as the first.

I would like to copy the whole directory to a new location (for testing) and have database one still link to the table in database two, but the linkage is still to the original directory, not the new location.

I'd like to do one of two things: either

1. Make the link to the table in database two in such a way that the folder path is relative - that the path to database two isn't hardcoded.

   or
2. Have a routine in `Form_Load` (or an autoexec macro) that checks the application.path and programmatically adjusts the linkage accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

It can be useful to have a start-up form that allows you to browse for the back-end you want and a table of the tables that should be linked. You could iterate through the tables collection, but i think a list is slightly safer. After that, a little code is all that is needed, here is a snippet:

```
''Connection string with database password 
strConnect = "MS Access;PWD=pw;DATABASE=" & Me.txtNewDataDirectory

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select TableName From LinkTables " _
& "WHERE TableType = 'LINK'")

Do While Not rs.EOF
    ''Check if the table is already linked, if it is, update the connection
    ''otherwise, link the table. 

    If IsNull(DLookup("[Name]", "MSysObjects", "[Name]='" & rs!TableName & "'")) Then
        Set tdf = db.CreateTableDef(rs!TableName, dbAttachSavePWD, _
            rs!TableName, strConnect)
        db.TableDefs.Append tdf
    Else
        db.TableDefs(rs!TableName).Connect = strConnect
    End If
    db.TableDefs(rs!TableName).RefreshLink
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks !<P>(I should have known it was something in a system table.)

Comment: @user581943 The system table stuff is only used to find if the link exists, Connect is the property of the TableDef that needs to be changed if the link does exist.

Comment: the usual method is to loop through the TableDefs collection and either check if there's a Connect string or use the system propert that identifies a linked table.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton I am fully aware of that and I say above "You could iterate through the tables collection, but i think a list is slightly safer." If, for some reason, a link has been deleted, a list of tables that should be there is going to be very useful. Try it, it saves time in development, too.

Comment: OK -- I didn't read carefully. I thought you were looping MSysObjects, which would have the same flaw as walking the TableDefs collection. I don't see the benefit in having a list table because I can't quite conceive of a situation where a linked table would be deleted and that not be reflected in the front end already.

Comment: Is there a difference between the rs and RS in the "Set tdf" statement?  Or are you repeating that parameter?  (It seems like you would repeat them if you want the linked table to have the same name as the source table.)  I don't have a password, so I left that parameter blank and had the same 1st and 3rd parameters (![linked_table]), but I'm getting an error on the next line:  "Run-time error 3264: No field defined--cannot append TableDef or Index."

Comment: @rryanp There are the same, VBA is not case sensitive. You cannot omit the attributes parameter, but you can use 0 instead of dbAttachSavePWD.

Comment: What is rs?  What is strConnect?  What is db?  What is tdf?  Why don't you include variable declarations?

Comment: The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'LinkTables'.  Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks,

I used it succesfull, however did not use it with the recordset.

```
Const LnkDataBase = "C:\NorthWind.mdb"
Sub relinktables()
'Routine to relink the tables automatically. Change the constant LnkDataBase to the desired one and run the sub
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim strTable As String
Set dbs = CurrentDb()
For Each tdf In dbs.TableDefs
    If Len(tdf.Connect) > 1 Then 'Only relink linked tables
        If tdf.Connect <> ";DATABASE=" & LnkDataBase Then 'only relink tables if the are not linked right
            If Left(tdf.Connect, 4) <> "ODBC" Then 'Don't want to relink any ODBC tables
                strTable = tdf.Name
                dbs.TableDefs(strTable).Connect = ";DATABASE=" & LnkDataBase
                dbs.TableDefs(strTable).RefreshLink
            End If
        End if
    End If
Next tdf
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a great version. It worked for me without any customization.

Answer (score 2):

I used usncahill's solution and modified it for my own needs.  I do not have enough reputation to vote up their solution, so if you like my additional code, please vote us both up.

I wanted a quick way to switch between two back-end databases, one containing live data and the other containing test data.  So I modified the previously mentioned code as follows:

```
Private Sub ReplaceLink(oldLink As String, newLink As String)
    Dim tbl As TableDef, db As Database

    Set db = CurrentDb

    For Each tbl In db.TableDefs
        If InStr(tbl.Connect, oldLink) > 0 Then
            tbl.Connect = Replace(tbl.Connect, oldLink, newLink)
            tbl.RefreshLink
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Public Function ConnectTestDB()
    ReplaceLink "Data.accdb", "Test.accdb"
End Function

Public Function ConnectLiveDB()
    ReplaceLink "Test.accdb", "Data.accdb"
End Function

Public Function TestDBSwitch()
    Dim tbl As TableDef, db As Database
    Dim wasData As Boolean
    Dim wasTest As Boolean

    wasData = False
    wasTest = False

    Set db = CurrentDb

    For Each tbl In db.TableDefs
        If InStr(tbl.Connect, "JGFC Flooring Data") > 0 Then
            wasData = True
        ElseIf InStr(tbl.Connect, "JGFC Flooring Test") > 0 Then
            wasTest = True
        End If
    Next

    If wasData = True And wasTest = True Then
        MsgBox "Data Mismatch.  Both Test and Live Data are currently linked! Connecting all tables to Test database. To link to Live database, please run again.", , "Data Mismatch"
        ConnectTestDB
    ElseIf wasData = True Then
        ConnectTestDB
        MsgBox "You are now connected to the Test database.", , "Connection Changed"
    ElseIf wasTest = True Then
        ConnectLiveDB
        MsgBox "You are now connected to the Live database.", , "Connection Changed"
    End If
 End Function
```

*(The previous code assumes that both the Test and Live Data files are located in the same directory and the file name ends in Test and Data, but can be easily modified to other paths/filenames)*

I call TestSwitchDB from a button in my front-end DB to quickly change between testing and production environments.  My Access DB has user controls to switch between user environments, so when the admin user logs in to the front-end DB, I use the ConnectTestDB function directly to default the admin user to connect to the test DB.  I likewise, use the ConnectLiveDB function when other users login to the front-end.

There is also a quick error detection in the TestSwitchDB function to tell me if there are a mix of connections to both environments prior to calling the switch function.  If this error is recurrent, it could be a sign of other issues.

Comment: worked well! runs way much faster than changing it manually with access UI itself.

Answer (score 1):

Our corporate IT changed the pathing our shared files from local to corporate, which necessitated redirecting all of our database tables. This would have a been pain, to delete and recreate all the links, especially with multiple different databases linked. I found this question but neither of the other answers worked well for me. The following is what I used. Note, this will take awhile with many tables as each update might take a few seconds.

```
Public Sub Fix_Table_Locations()
    Dim tbl As TableDef, db As Database, strConnect As String

    Set db = CurrentDb

    For Each tbl In db.TableDefs
        If InStr(tbl.Connect, "Portion of connect string to change") > 0 Then
            tbl.Connect = Replace(tbl.Connect, "Portion of connect string to change", "New portion of connect string")
            tbl.RefreshLink
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @technoman23 This link explains the cause (tl;dr: might be missing a driver for the linked file containing the target table) https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/209805/you-receive-a-could-not-find-installable-isam-error-message-or-some-fi

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use a relative path depending on where the files are located. The default location where Access looks is in Documents (C:\Users\UserName\Documents). So if you enter .. then it will take you one folder up from Documents, which is the user's folder. For example if your database file will always be stored at

C:\Users\UserName\Access App\Access Database

Then you can enter "..\Access App\Database" as the relevant file location. Otherwise you have to use VBA. In my case the file/file folders may not always be in the same location, some users may store the files on their Google drive, while others may use My Documents or the desktop. I was able to use a function similar to what usncahill posted:

```
Sub relinkBackendDB()
    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim connectionString As String
    Dim tbl As TableDef
    Dim db As Database

    sFilePath = (Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\system\Dojo Boss Database.accdb")
    connectionString = ("MS Access;PWD=MyPassword;DATABASE=" & sFilePath)
    Set db = CurrentDb

    For Each tbl In db.TableDefs
        If Len(tbl.Connect) > 0 Then
            'MsgBox tbl.Connect 'If you're getting errors, uncomment this to see connection string syntax
            tbl.Connect = connectionString
            tbl.RefreshLink
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I call this function via the on_load event procedure when my "Home" form loads up, so it gets called whenever the app is first loaded/opened. This way it will always look in the relevant file folder, no matter what the user name is.