# ms access 2000 changing linked tables without using Linked table manager

Tags: ms-access, linked-tables

I'm using MS ACCESS 2000. 
I have few tables in AB.mdb linked to some other table XY.mdb in my machine. Its working fine in my machine local.

Now if i move this AB.mdb to some other machine its showing error as its is searching for XY.mdb in its local machine.

I cannot change path in that machine using linked table manager because we dont have access from that machine.

Is there any way to solve this issue.

any way to change path of linked tabels **other than linked table manager**

Thanks,

Shanmugam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the linked tables target programmatically in VBA.

[Access: Changing linked table location programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928134/access-changing-linked-table-location-programatically)
[Reconnect Attached tables on Start-up](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-13.html)
[Relink tables in code](http://www.fabalou.com/Access/Modules/refreshtables.asp)

Comment: No problem, welcome to SO. Have a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Cularis, But my issue is in AB.mdb only few tables should be changed using liked table programmatically. Solution you gave is like to change everything? is there any other way?

Comment: You can alter the solution to only change some columns?

Comment: Ya i tried Relink Tables in Code- third link which you have given. In that we are getting " Select a Data Source " box to select a table. But issue here is i cannot add that sever path to my network places i dont have acces.... but some how i have to use that in ms access application?

Comment: I also have a reconnect utility that works with multiple back ends: http://dfenton.com/DFA/download/Access/Reconnect.html -- this is an Access FAQ, basically remedial Access and there are solutions for it all over the Internet. The most basic Google search should have produced working solutions within the first five links.