# Refresh table link

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access, linked-tables

I found the following function while browsing the Web that allows me to dynamically link a table to my Access database at the execution:

```vb
Function createAttached(strTable As String, strPath As String, strBaseTable As String) As Boolean

'************************************************************************************
'* Create an attached table in the current database from a table in a different MDB file.
'* In:                                                                              *
'*   strTable - name of linked table to create                                      *
'*   strPath - path and name of MDB file containing the table                       *
'*   strBaseTable - name of table in strPath MDB                                    *
'* Out:                                                                             *
'*   Return value: True/False, indicating success                                   *
'* Modifies:                                                                        *
'*   Nothing, but adds a new table.                                                 *
'************************************************************************************

On Error GoTo CreateAttachedError

Dim tdf As TableDef
Dim strConnect As String
Dim fRetval As Boolean
Dim myDB As Database

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    Set myDB = CurrentDb
    Set tdf = myDB.CreateTableDef(strTable)

    With tdf
        .Connect = ";DATABASE=" & strPath
        .SourceTableName = strBaseTable
    End With

    myDB.TableDefs.Append tdf

    fRetval = True

    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

CreateAttachedExit:
    createAttached = fRetval
    Exit Function

CreateAttachedError:
    If Err = 3110 Then
        Resume CreateAttachedExit
    Else
        If Err = 3011 Then
            Resume Next
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

This script works, however, if the table is already linked, it just does nothing (but an error event is still triggerered). I would like the same script to delete the linked table if it exists, or at least refresh that link so that the path is the right one. I have no idea of how to do this, it's probably quite simple but I don't know where to start.

Thank you.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606326/linked-table-ms-access-2010-change-connection-string/12608244#12608244

Comment: You again? hehe. And oops, I don't know why I didn't find that post earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I use. It also tests for if the table is a linked table before trying to refresh the link.
This code assumes that the db you're linking to is in the same folder as the db you're linking from. If not, remove the "Application.CurrentProject.Path" and add the appropiate path.

```
Public Sub RelinkTables()
    Dim dbs As Database
    Dim Tdf As TableDef
    Dim Tdfs As TableDefs
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set Tdfs = dbs.TableDefs
    For Each Tdf In Tdfs
        If Tdf.SourceTableName <> "" Then 'If the table source is other than a base table
            Tdf.Connect = ";DATABASE=" & Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\filename.accdb" 'Set the new source
            Tdf.RefreshLink 'Refresh the link
        End If
    Next 'Goto next table
End Sub
```

Comment: I would be inclined to check the connection for a database name, not the source table. It is not uncommon to link from more than one source.

Comment: If I'm linking from more than 1 source, I usually have a local table with all the linked table names and the DB they link to.

Comment: Tested and working with .RefreshLink. The solution posted by Remou doesn't work however, TabledDefs doesn't exist and .Refresh isn't a property of tdf.