# VBA - Update Linked Table of an Access file from Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to change the linked table address from an Access file "Hey.accdb" using VBA coding from an Excel file.

I've coded the script below in my Excel file and it prompts the error "Object required" when I run it.  Can someone please help me with this problem.  I've been staring at it for too long.  Thanks.

```
Sub RunMacroinAccesswithPara2()

Set Db = CreateObject("Access.Application")
        Db.OpenCurrentDatabase "D:\Database1\Hey.accdb"
        Db.Visible = True
        Db.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow

    DoCmd.TransferDatabase TransferType:=acLink, _
        DatabaseType:="Microsoft Access", _
        DatabaseName:="V:\Reporting\Quarterly\2018Q2\JP\Data\04\Database\Valuation_Database.mdb", _
        ObjectType:=acTable, _
        Source:="Valuation_Database_Adjusted", _
        Destination:="Valuation_Database_Adjusted"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DoCmd` belongs to the Access application object.

So use

```
Db.DoCmd.TransferDatabase ' etc.
```

**Edit**

To update the link, you need the `TableDef` object, set its `.Connect` property and run `.RefreshLink`.

See [Linked table ms access 2010 change connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606326/linked-table-ms-access-2010-change-connection-string)

Comment: Hi Andre! This works.  However, it creates a duplicate table.  Is there anyway I could just update the existing table's linkage (without using delete table then transferdatabase)?